# What is the difference between Sign, DigestSign, and Digest?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, sign, evp-cipher

I'm implementing hashing (aka. digest) and signing in an app that uses the OpenSSL EVP API. However the API has three very similar methods, which are confusing:

- [`Sign`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_SignInit.html) which sounds like it should be used for signing, however `EVP_SignInit` is simply a `#define` to `EVP_DigestInit`
- [`Digest`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html) which seems like it can only be used only for hash generation, there is no way to specify an `EVP_PKEY`.
- [`DigestSign`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_DigestSignInit.html) which looks like it does both the hashing and the signing.

But [the documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) recomments to use `DigestSign` for signing (and not the actual `Sign`).

I'm not a cryptography expert, so this is very confusing to me. What is the difference between them? Which one is a good choice for implementing signing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can be found in the documentation for `EVP_SignInit`:

> Since the private key is passed in the call to `EVP_SignFinal()` any error relating to the private key (for example an unsuitable key and digest combination) will not be indicated until after potentially large amounts of data have been passed through `EVP_SignUpdate()`.
>
> It is not possible to change the signing parameters using these function.
>
> The previous two bugs are fixed in the newer `EVP_SignDigest()` function.

Note: I copied this verbatim, the functions are called `EVP_DigestSign` not `EVP_SignDigest`.

So it is a replacement function for two bugs that couldn't be amended by the previous API. Of course you'd want to have the old API to be there and behave the same way for backward compatibility.

So the old API didn't adhere to the principles of *fail fast* or *least surprise*; you don't want to crash after hashing the message because a bad scheme is used: the scheme to use is generally established *beforehand*.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `DigestSign` is the new API? There is no `SignDigest`.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about the typo, but I didn't make it, I copied it verbatim.

Comment: One more question: what exactly does `DigestSign` do? First calculate a digest and then sign it? Or...?

Comment: Yep, that's the general order of signature generation. It would be tricky to do it the other way, right?

Comment: Is it possible to sign something without first hashing it?

Comment: Generally that's not something that is ever performed. There are signatures with partial message recovery, but even those are first hashing the message, and then include (part of) the message *and* the hash in the RSA operation.

Comment: You can in principle forego the hashing and use the message, **if** the message is sufficiently small. Of course anybody that can decrypt can retrieve the message (which is generally no problem in sign-then-encrypt). You **do** however need to include the padding before you perform the modular exponentiation required for RSA. (EC)DSA is a different kettle of fish, and you may need to hash or exclude some message patterns. More info [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12768/1172)